# Centering google maps from address

Tags: javascript, maps

I would like to center a google map from an address I get from a database with laravel. However the map isn't showing. Where is the problem?

```html
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        getLocations();
      }
      
      function getLocations() {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('GET', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + {{ $address }} + '&key=AIzaSyCkCcwU02g9AlDkBzL6S6MbRBUNi8Z7atI', true);

        http.onload = function() {

          var coordinates = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
          coordinates = coordinates['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];

          var event = {lat: coordinates['lat'], lng: coordinates['lng']};
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: event
          });
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event,
            map: map
          });
        };

        http.send();
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkCcwU02g9AlDkBzL6S6MbRBUNi8Z7atI&callback=initMap">
 </script>
```

Comment: Also not a good idea to include your private key in public posts. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should show a bit more of your code, and give error codes returned. 
Anyhow I think it's either the way you pass the address or the way you have your html setup. A quick way to check if it's a good address is placing an alert. Or you could test for a 200 response from the server.

Look at the following code that works 
and here is the snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
        getLocations();
      }

      function getLocations() {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('GET', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&&key=AIzaSyCkCcwU02g9AlDkBzL6S6MbRBUNi8Z7atI', true);

        http.onload = function() {

          var coordinates = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
          coordinates = coordinates['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];

          var event = {lat: coordinates['lat'], lng: coordinates['lng']};
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 12,
            center: event
          });
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event,
            map: map
          });
        };

        http.send();
      }


    </script>

    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkCcwU02g9AlDkBzL6S6MbRBUNi8Z7atI&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```